# How do I find pdf of $X^2$ when $X$ has pdf $f_X(x)=\frac29(x+1)$ for $-1<x<2$?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

> Let $X$ have the pdf $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}\frac29(x+1)&,-1<x<2 \\ 0&,\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ 
>   Find the pdf of $Y=X^2$.

The transformation isn't one-to-one so I’m a bit confused as to how to split the range of y and derive the pdf. In a previous question, the range of y included both negative and positive values. So I found out the corresponding range of X for negative and positive y’s respectively. But here the range of y is from 0 to 4. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ has CDF $\frac19(x+1)^2$ on $[-1,\,2]$, each $y\in[0,\,4]$ satisfies$$P(X^2\le y)=P(X\in[-\sqrt{y},\,\sqrt{y}])=\frac{(\sqrt{y}+1)^2-(1-\min\{\sqrt{y},\,1\})^2}{9}.$$The PDF is obtained from this CDF by differentiation, viz.$$\frac{1+y^{-1/2}-1_{[0,\,1]}(y)(1-y^{-1/2})}{9}$$in terms of an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). In particular, for $y\in[0,\,1]$ the PDF is $\frac29y^{-1/2}$, while for $y\in[1,\,4]$ it's $\frac19(1+y^{-1/2})$. We can equivalently rewrite it as $\frac19(y^{-1/2}+\min\{1,\,y^{-1/2}\})$.

Comment: Why is 1 (in the domain of y) the point of demarcation for which we have two pdfs?

Comment: @AP_ Because $y\in[1,\,4]$ have unique preimages in $[1,\,2]$.

Comment: Ah yes,okay. Now, a solution I’d found said that the CDF of Y would be P[-1<=X<= y^1/2], when 1<=y<4. I can’t understand why -1 came here. I’m sorry for the non-math notation.

Comment: Or is that a mistake by the person who wrote it, and it should be +1? Please help.

Comment: @AP_ We have two constraints on $x$ for a given $y$: one is that $x=\pm\sqrt{y}$, the other is that $x\in[-1,\2]$.If $y\in[0,\,1]$, two values of $x$ are possible; if $y\in(1,\,4]$, only one is.